# Is there a way to change the Batchsize of MongoDB permanently?

Tags: mongodb, batchsize

I want to make some test of a API I've written between MongoDB and SWI-PROLOG. So the problem I'm facing is the batch-size of MongoDB. Can I permanently set it up to 1.000.000?

I haven't found anything in the documantation of MongoDB.

I know I can change it via:

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1999
```

But not permanantly.

Answer (score 1):

Batch size is a client setting, therefore to change it "permanently" configure it on the client the way you want it to be.

Comment: Is there a way to set it “permanently” on the client ?

Answer (score 1):

The default batch size is hardcoded [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r4.4.6/src/mongo/db/query/query_request.cpp#L67)

You'll need to recompile to change it.